# 'dotnet restore' is failing when mixing a private NuGet feed with public one

Tags: c#, console, nuget, artifactory

I have project using packages from both private feed with authentication (jfrog based) and public one.

Restoring packages from IDE like Rider or VS is working fine, however when I am using console it is failing with 401 authorization error.

Any idea how can I fix it?

My global nuget.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="jfrog-based-nuget" value="https://myprivate.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/myprivate-nuget" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Example error:

```
error : Failed to retrieve information about '<private-package-name>' from remote source '<private-feed>/FindPackagesById()?id='<package-name>'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'. [<solution-path>]
error : Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [<solution-path>]
```

Comment: Does your nuget config have the appropriate fields about the repository's username and password, inside `<packageSourceCredentials>` ?

Comment: I don't have that node in my config file (it is whole config file), however I can see in IDE that Rider remembers my credentials to private repo.

Comment: Find the repo in the artifactory UI and click the "Set me up" button, it will give you all the config you need

Comment: I have it set up in Rider IDE and it is working there. It is stored somewhere, because VS IDE also works and managed to read my credentials. I was also trying to add manually packageSourceCredentials node, but it seems it doesn't work. Could you add example for this? I wonder about password type that I should use if I get access to artifactory by API key.